# how to compare two array and remove the same values by swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, compare

var string1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
var string2 = ["B"]

how to get the following result? Thanks so much!

var result = ["A","C"]

Comment: What if string2 had element "D"? Should the result include "D"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `filter` to filter out any elements in `string1` that are contained in `string2`:

```
let result = string1.filter { !string2.contains($0) }
```

---

*See comments section for a discussion about the possibility of using `Set` for similar operations that would be faster with large arrays*

Comment: better to use a set

Comment: I debated using `Set` a answer like `subtracting`, but it didn't seem like there was an explicitly better reason in this case. Can you elaborate on what is "better" about it in this case? Or is the assumption that it would be better at scale?

Comment: It would only make a big difference in performance if you have a large array. What I meant was to create a set from string2 and use `!set.contains($0)`

Comment: Gotcha -- so, yes, at scale. I wonder (and, of course, I could easily benchmark when back in front of a computer) if the conversion from `Array` to `Set` would eat up any performance benefits if one weren't careful to use `Set` from the beginning. For the assumption that the OP is a Swift beginner, I think my current answer is probably a good beginner choice, but I will add a note to check the comments.

Comment: OP can create a set instead of an array. So converting might not even be needed. We don't have enough info about it but OP might not even know about `Set`.

Comment: You're right -- there's not enough information. For example, the first array might be coming from a function in an API where they're receiving an array and not a set. Now, with the pointer to the comments, they should know to at least check out `Set` and see what it offers them.

Comment: Even when converting from `Array` to `Set` might be desired depending on the size of the collection to be filtered. Don't forget that `Set` contains is `O(1)` while `Array` contains is `O(n)`.

Comment: This is a assuming that that the original set contains unique values, too. If the input were `A,A,B,C` and then intent were to keep both `A`, then `Set` obviously wouldn't do the job. Again, not enough detail in the question.

Comment: Ah — right. My mistake.